# Make statistical expression for field calculator

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, statistics

I have a vector layer called 'Stations' and a table called 'Attitude' and a relation exists between the table's ('Attitude') "Staion_id" field and vector layer's ('Stations') "uuid" field.

Below is the 'Station'(Parent layer) layers fields.

[image]

And These are the 'Attitude'(child layer) table's field.

[image]

I wanted to build a expression in "DD" field of 'Stations' layer that would do the following statistical tasks

Get the "DD" values from the 'Attitude' child layers for the corresponding feature (or the children of "DD" in 'Station' layer.). Then remove the outliers by removing the values smaller than

> q1 (1st Quartile) - 1.5iqr (inter quartile range)

and larger than

> q1 (1st Quartile) - 1.5iqr (inter quartile range)

Then it will bring the median value and populate the "DD" in 'Stations' or parent layer.
and also populate the "AD" in the 'Stations' layer with value of "AD" that belongs to the median value for "DD" in the 'Attitude' or child layer.

I have tried to use the aggregate function but failed to construct one as I am new in QGIS environment.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your q1 - 1.5 iqr calculation is for - both conditions are identical (so the value you want must be equal to q1 - (1.5 * iqr) ? but this will not necessarily generate a value that is present your dataset so you will get no results) Do you mean you just want the median value? I've written an answer that assumes just that but you should clarify what statistical calculation you're actually after.

Comment: Also, what do you want to do when the median is of an even number of values? Normally you'd take the mean of the two values either side, but you may not then get a value for AD...

Answer (score 1):

Assume you just want the median `DD` value for each `uuid`/`station_id` category, you can use this expression in Field Calculator on the Stations layer (replace `'stations-attitudes'` with the name of your relation):

```sql
 relation_aggregate('stations-attitudes','median',"DD")
```

However, if you have an even number of matching `DD` values, then the median value will not be an actual `DD` value (e.g. `DD` values are `1, 2, 3, 4` - median is `2.5`), so it won't be possible to find the corresponding `AD` value.

---

##### Get "central values" instead of median

One option is to get the "central" values:

- Odd-numbered set of values (e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`) - get 1 central value (`3`)
- Even-numbered set of values (e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4`) - get 2 central values  (`2` and `3`)

Based off the concept in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75605105) you can use this expression on the Stations layer to get the central `DD` value(s) as an array, converted to a comma-delimited string.

However note that the expression below needs to be stored in a text field:

```sql
array_to_string(
    with_variable('arr_dd',
                  relation_aggregate('stations-attitudes',
                                     'array_agg',
                                     "dd",
                                     order_by:="dd"),
                  array_distinct(
                      array_foreach(array(floor((array_length(@arr_dd)-1)/2),
                                          ceil((array_length(@arr_dd)-1)/2)),
                                   array_get(@arr_dd,@element)
                                   )
                                )
                    )
             )
```

You will get a result like `2,3` (for an array `1, 2, 3, 4`) or `3` (for an array `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`).

---

##### Look up other values using comma-delimited "central values"

You can then get the corresponding `AD` values from the Attitudes layer like so - unfortunately you can't use `relation_aggregate()` as it won't let you filter from the parent layer while referencing the child layer.

In the example below, the previously calculated field on the Stations layer is called `median_DD` for clarity's sake in this expression:

Again, the results must be stored in a text field.

```sql
array_to_string(
    aggregate('Attitudes',
              'array_agg',
              "ad",
              "station_id"=attribute(@parent,'uuid') AND 
              array_contains(string_to_array(attribute(@parent,'median_DD')),
                            "dd")
              )
)
```

Note unless your original `DD` values are unique, you may end up with more than one matching `AD` value. See the example below with `station_id` numbers `3` and `4` (green and blue boxes)

---

An example:

[image]

---

You can tweak the above to do other operations with the "central values".

For example, instead of storing multiple `DD` or `AD` values, you could retrieve only the higher/highest value - use `array_max()` instead of `array_to_string()`. Then you can store your results in a numeric field.